# How to understand the routing in ASP.Net Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I am trying to learn ASP.Net Web API. And I have a *MVC controller* Home and from there I want to make a call to *API Controller* which is CoursesController via ajax call. But I am not able to make the ajax call to the api controller when I give the complete valid path.

**Case 1:** *Working example*: If I go to **localhost:port/**

q. HomeController's Index mathod gets hit

b. Then CoursesApiController gets hit and result is displayed

**Case 2:** *Non Working Example*: If I go to **localhost:port/Home/Index**

a. HomeController's Index method gets hit

b. But ApiController does not get hit

**Chrome Dev error:**

It tries to attempt to open API URI pointing at **localhost:port/Home/api/Courses** (which obviously is wrong).

But why does it work fine when I don't explicitly tell the URL in browser?

Routes.Config File:

```
  routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

WebApi.config File:

```
   config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Index.cshtml File:

```
<div >
    hello worl
    <ol id="courses"></ol>
</div>
@section scripts
{
    <script>
        $.ajax({
            url: 'api/courses', // here I am making the API Call to Courses controller
            success: function (courses) {
                debugger;
                var list = $('#courses');
                for (var i = 0; i < courses.length; i++)
                {
                    var course = courses[i];
                    list.append('<li>' + course.title + '</li>');
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `localhost:port/api/Courses` ? try `url: '/api/courses'`

Comment: But why does it work when I simply tell it to go to Localhost:port. I mean it understands that it needs to go to HomeController and then to Index.cshtml -> and then makes the API call.

Comment: But why it stops working when I explicitly tell it to go to localhost:port/Home/Index.

Comment: Both are same thing right. In  both case default route is being taken. But why it works fine in case 1, but does not work in case 2.

Comment: It generates the wrong url (it adds "Home" to the url) which is not needed.

Comment: Check this https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/03/27/webapi-tip-5-generating-links.aspx

Comment: @Shyju: Below answer give by Nate did the trick. But I still need to know why case 1 worked for me. I will read the link you mentioned. :) Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a bug/typo in your url in the javascript.

You have: `url: 'api/courses',`

Should be: `url: '/api/courses',`

This is due to how the browser handles relative paths.

If your browser is sitting at http://localhost:port/ the script will work since the relative path is correct. Once you manually route to `/home` or `/home/index` the relative path is now pointing to `/home/index/api` which isn't what you want.

Ultimately a javascript path fragment that does not start with a '/' is treated as relative to the current browser path. A path that starts with a '/' is treated as an absolute path.

Comment: Thank you so so much. Its working now. Can you explain. even with error why case 1 was working. Please tell me. :)